# create a page in AEM dynamically with input from csv

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

I would like to create around 100s of pages from a common template for multiple locales and different websites with a simple component that includes a script and that script has to get a key from a csv file for the respective locale.

Below cURL will create page with a common template but how to add component:

*curl -u admin:admin –F cmd="createPage" -F label="" -F parentPath="/content/geometrixx/en/company" -F template="/apps/geometrixx/templates/contentpage" -F title="new page" http://localhost:4502/bin/wcmcommand*

Answer (score 0):

If you know the JCR path where the component goes you can send a POST to the JCR path where you want to put the component and use the form data to provide the necessary info to create your component such as `sling:resourceType` or any other authored properties necessary.

You can see the example POST by going into AEM and:

1. Open an authored page of a template you are using in Chrome
2. open Chrome developer tools - > go to network tab
3. Drag a component into the page and watch for the post show up in the network panel.
4. You can right click on this line in the developer console and copy the URL as curl from the context menu.